# How to count a metrics across exectuors in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a spark job running with many executors.

I want to be able to use a counter on the executors to count the the number of occurrences of an event. For example count the number of times the column "column" is 10.

```
df.map(df => if(df.get("column")==10){ counter.inc } ; df)
```

I ultimately want the total to be the sum of counters across all executors.
Is this possible?

When we are reporting metrics from a spark driver we extend org.apache.spark.metrics.source.Source and register it in the spark env. can these metrics be used on the executors ever?

Comment: Have you tried with accumulators using udfs?. Spark UDAFS can help too

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to use the Spark aggregation "sum".

Thus the Spark will internally execute the aggregation in a distributed way in all the nodes and then return the aggreagate back to the driver.

```
df.withColumn("count_flag", when(col("column")==10, 1).otherwise(0))
  .agg(sum("count_flag") as "Total_Occurance_Of_Column_Value_10")
  .show()
```

Comment: The reason I don't love this solution is that you need to create 2 dags, one in my case which is writing to kafka and one just to compute a metric. 
Am I correct in saying that?

Comment: @Funzo, OK I got it, if that is the case , use a "window aggregate" in the same main DAG , so that you will not have additional DAG for metric

Comment: I don't really know how to do that, would you be able to give a little example and I will accept this answer.